# Python: Include complete package in another package

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, packaging

I have a package named 'firstlib' which I want to include completely in another package while keeping the code separated.

For example, the directory structure looks like this:

```
Proj1/
  setup.py
  firstlib/
    __init__.py
    mod1.py
    subpack/
      ...
Proj2/
  setup.py
  otherlib/
    __init__.py
    mod2.py
    ...
```

Now i want to be able to use 'firstlib' as a standalone package but also as a subpackage of 'otherlib'. Assuming both packages are installed, what needs to be done to make these lines work:

```py
from firstlib import mod1
from otherlib.firstlib import mod1
```

So basicaly I want the namespace of `firstlib` in the same namespace as modules of `otherlib`. In a way like a namespace package.

Comment: You are trying to implement wrong approach. There is no term like "subpackage" in python. Add `firstlib` to PyPI index and specify it as dependency for `otherlib` in its `setup.py`.

Comment: I knwo that I can specify ```firstlib```as dependency of ```otherlib```. But this would not make possible the mentioned imports.

Comment: Probably something goes wrong if you need it.

Comment: @Raz, what do you mean with "something goes wrong"?

Comment: I mean that people don't need it and it is suspicious that you do. May be you actually don't need it too and it is possible to solve you problem with a common approach. Could you explain what do you want to archive?